# External Toolbar not hiding properly (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the external toolbar (header). According to the jQuery Mobile documentation it is supposed to hide automatically if any page has an internal header, but for some reason it doesn't.

I found a partial solution on jQuery Mobile forum. I check before showing the page if the internal header exists in it and if yes, hide the external one:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow",function(){
  var activePage = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage');
  if(activePage.find("div[data-role=header]").length > 0 ){
      $("#external-header").hide();
  } else {
      $("#external-header").show();
  }
});
```

Here is the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/io_phoenix/a9wt3hbf/7/

The problem that I have is that external header is not hiding on page #0 the first time the file is loaded, it does only when I navigate to this page later using internal links.

I don't understand why 'before show' is not working in this case and I'm getting desperate trying to make it work :(

Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take the pagecontainerbeforeshow event handler out of the jQuery ready function and place it before your body close tag. Placing it in the ready function might allow jQM to enhance pagezero before the handler is added.

If you look at the **[API DOC](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-beforeshow)** for pagebeforeshow, you can use the second argument to get the page you are navigating to (`ui.toPage`):

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow", function(event, ui){
    var activePage = ui.toPage;
    if(activePage.find("div[data-role=header]").length > 0 ) {
        $("#external-header").hide();
    } else {
        $("#external-header").show();
    }
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/a9wt3hbf/10/)**

Comment: Thank you for the help! It gives a strange jumping effect on page#2 but actually looks and works perfect in my project.